# Create a data frame with as.data.frame with differing numbers of rows in R

Tags: r, httr, jsonlite

I want to extract data from an API with some specifications.
I have a json file as a list of length two. I want to generate a data frame with the function as.data.frame for the whole data set to be able to export it to Excel.
Therefore I used the following code:

```
Interest <- GET("https://api.aleth.io/v0/defi/history?protocols=maker,compound,aave,dydx,ddex&assets=dai,usdc,usdt,tusd&metrics=earn_apr,borrow_apr&before=1601424000&after=1577836800")
Interest_content <- content(Interest, as="text", encoding = "UTF-8")
Interest_data <- Interest_content
Interest_jsondata <- jsonlite::fromJSON(Interest_data)
Interest_dataFrame <- as.data.frame(Interest_jsondata)
```

When calling the function as.data.frame on the json data, the following error is generated:

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 4, 2, 5

When looking into the Interest_jsondata, it occurs that the number of items (the number of rows) in "points" are differing. I guess that´s why the error in the as.data.frame function is generated.

How can that error be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look a the structure of `Interest_jsondata` .

```
str(Interest_jsondata)
List of 2
 $ data:'data.frame':   22 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ asset   : chr [1:22] "usdc" "usdc" "dai" "dai" ...
  ..$ metric  : chr [1:22] "earn_apr" "borrow_apr" "earn_apr" "borrow_apr" ...
  ..$ points  :List of 22
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:266, 1:2] "1578528000" "1578614400" "1578700800" "1578787200" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:266, 1:2] "1578528000" "1578614400" "1578700800" "1578787200" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:266, 1:2] "1578528000" "1578614400" "1578700800" "1578787200" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:266, 1:2] "1578528000" "1578614400" "1578700800" "1578787200" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:266, 1:2] "1578528000" "1578614400" "1578700800" "1578787200" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:266, 1:2] "1578528000" "1578614400" "1578700800" "1578787200" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:266, 1:2] "1578528000" "1578614400" "1578700800" "1578787200" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:266, 1:2] "1578528000" "1578614400" "1578700800" "1578787200" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:274, 1:2] "1577836800" "1577923200" "1578009600" "1578096000" ...
  ..$ protocol: chr [1:22] "compound" "compound" "compound" "compound" ...
 $ meta:List of 1
  ..$ params:List of 6
  .. ..$ after      : int 1577836800
  .. ..$ assets     : chr [1:4] "tusd" "usdc" "usdt" "dai"
  .. ..$ before     : int 1601424000
  .. ..$ granularity: int 24
  .. ..$ metrics    : chr [1:2] "earn_apr" "borrow_apr"
  .. ..$ protocols  : chr [1:5] "compound" "aave" "ddex" "dydx" ...
```

The first item is the list is a data.frame! The second item is another list. Maybe all you need to do is extract the first item?

```
Interest_dataFrame <- Interest_jsondata$data
```

This works without error. The resulting data.frame has a list column in it (`points`), and each item in `points` looks like a matrix. The numbers of points in each matrix is not consistent, and how you deal with them is going to depend on your ultimate goal.

Here are some `dplyr` functions to help visalize the data.frame better:

```
library(dplyr)
glimpse(Interest_dataFrame)
Rows: 22
Columns: 4
$ asset    <chr> "usdc", "usdc", "dai", "dai", "tusd", "tusd", "usdc", "usdc",...
$ metric   <chr> "earn_apr", "borrow_apr", "earn_apr", "borrow_apr", "earn_apr...
$ points   <list> [<"1577836800", "1577923200", "1578009600", "1578096000", "1...
$ protocol <chr> "compound", "compound", "compound", "compound", "aave", "aave...

as_tibble(Interest_dataFrame)
# A tibble: 22 x 4
   asset metric     points              protocol
   <chr> <chr>      <list>              <chr>   
 1 usdc  earn_apr   <chr[,2] [274 x 2]> compound
 2 usdc  borrow_apr <chr[,2] [274 x 2]> compound
 3 dai   earn_apr   <chr[,2] [274 x 2]> compound
 4 dai   borrow_apr <chr[,2] [274 x 2]> compound
 5 tusd  earn_apr   <chr[,2] [266 x 2]> aave    
 6 tusd  borrow_apr <chr[,2] [266 x 2]> aave    
 7 usdc  earn_apr   <chr[,2] [266 x 2]> aave    
 8 usdc  borrow_apr <chr[,2] [266 x 2]> aave    
 9 usdt  earn_apr   <chr[,2] [266 x 2]> aave    
10 usdt  borrow_apr <chr[,2] [266 x 2]> aave    
# ... with 12 more rows
```

The second element in your original json list gives some parameters for the data: initial and final values, the levels of factors, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! In the end I would like to include the points which are currently in a matrix, into a table structure. The points here describe different timestamps. I would like to assign the timestamps and rates for every asset on every protocol. How do I extract the points which are currently in a list into a reasonable table structure?

Comment: It seems that "points" contain the timestamps and the regarding interest rates in one. How can I decode this in a proper way to obtain timestamp and the fitting interest rate?